# God and Satan in the book of Job: how did they know about this conversation?

Tags: nature-of-god, old-testament, satan, job

Job chapter 1 vers 6 - 12 talks about God and Satan having a conversation.  Where does that story come from?

Job does not know what is going on and I have never heard anyone talk about it. Is it a revelation or is it a tradition that helps us understand what was said in this conversation?  Who knew and who was told that this conversation was going on?

(If there is not another Bible verse that can explain this question maybe the RCC or the Orthodox church have a tradition that can explain such a question).

The author is not as important; **how did the author know** is the important part.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).
Your question, though a good one, is probably not one we can answer here, since different people will have different opinions on the subject.
Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: In 1 Kings 22:19 a parallel story can be found.

Comment: Great question. And clearly there are many relevant pieces of the puzzle that are not opinion. Should be reopened

Answer (score 5):

Great Question, I was actually wondering the same thing for a while until I did some reading.
The entire bible was written with the Inspiration of God, as found in

> 2 Timothy 3:16 NKJV
>   16 All Scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness,

So basically God told the author what happened and what to write.For instance no one was there for the creation, God had to tell the author.

Comment: Thank you I think so as well.Well there are many ways to look at it as I see it.That might be true that God told the author ,maybe an angel came? But there are many options.Depends on your theology.Bible also says they lived for a loong time So It would seems they had some knowledge about the spiritual world and Adam was told by God  how the world was created.

Comment: So I think this is a more complicated question.I think in the Talmud it says That Moses did write Job and Moses  had revelations about alot of stuff and knew how to write this story.

Comment: A more complicated answer could be ,well might seem to be more of a Messianic view if any.Because of the feasts the 7 feasts in the bible an there connection with what is going on in heaven.So there might be a time of year when the angels come before God and speaks (they are his servants) As is a tradition in judaism that on Yom Kippur God judges the world.But Job was a good man and The answer Job gets is complicated . So I think my question is very interesting.Feel free to upvote I need the votes!!

Comment: Just to correct myself; God might have told Adam how the world was created

Answer (score 1):

The human author of Book of Job I believe received a vision and overheard a conversation and through God's grace gave him the wisdom to write the inspiration for purpose of stating that all the action of Satan are subject to Divine Providence. As St. Augustine said," if God will not restrict the action of the devil with his fury & hatred no man will be alive in a matter of time".

This writing can be paralleled to event that took place in 1884 when Pope Leo XIII had a vision of Satan talking to God. In that vision Satan was daring God that he can destroy the Catholic Church. But to do so,Satan ask for more power and more time (75 to 100 years). This vision leads to the formulation of St.Michael the Archangel Prayer to be prayed right after the Holy Mass celebration.

These two events: one in the Book of Job, the other in the vision of Pope Leo XIII.

Catechism of the Catholic Church teaches that God allows evil for greater good of man. As scriptures said "all things work for good for those who love him"

Like in the Garden of Eden, God allows Satan for the perfection of man. Man & Church will always be put to the test to attain a greater good, but as St. Paul with the temptation God will never put us to the test beyond our human strength to endure, and God will always give a way out.

> CCC 412  But why did God not prevent the first man from sinning?  St. Leo the Great responds, "Christ's inexpressible grace gave us blessings better than those the demon's envy had taken away."  And St. Thomas Aquinas wrote, "There is nothing to prevent human nature's being raised up to something greater, even after sin; God permits evil in order to draw forth some greater good.  Thus St. Paul says, 'Where sin increased, grace abounded all the more'; and the Exsultet sings, 'O happy fault,. . . which gained for us so great a Redeemer!'"

After Job passed the test, God rewarded Job with more blessings.

Comment: I edited your answer a bit, "..." as a stand-in for every possible punctuation isn't a good way to format answers...

Comment: Please check the edit I did, to make sure it fits what you are trying to offer as an answer.

Comment: Peter Turner yeah great edit...i appreciate it thanks.Godbless!

Comment: KorvinStarmast The author or authors of the book are unknown; it was probably composed some time between the seventh and fifth centuries B.C. This is a literary composition, and not a transcript of historical events and conversations.Pope John Paul II said Genesis 1-3 was myth - not meaning 
fairytale,but rather an ancient story put together to bring 
out some things true in themselves , so it is 
likely with the book of Job. Its real purpose is to explore 
the problem of suffering, of which we spoke above. Moses in RCC was not the author if is a literary material in nature.Godbless

Answer (score 1):

Most believe Moses authored Job.  This would make sense since the Bible says Moses spoke with God "face to face".

If so then this direct conversation with God could lead to learning about the inner workings of the Job story.

Remember that the book of Job quotes Job's friends who bear a false testimony, so in those sections what they say is not divinely inspired.  In fact one of them claims he heard what appears to be a demonic voice (Job 4:12-24)

Comment: Please check my edit to make sure that what you mean was preserved.  Also, please provide a supporting citation for "Most believe Moses authored Job"  That would improve your answer.

Comment: Never heard about the last part

Comment: Of course if the bible relays a conversation and one of the participants is evil then their quotes are, in some sense, not divinely inspired. Except maybe the conversation as a whole still is. Thats all he’s saying about Job’s relatives. That they lie and are quoted in the story, even as lying. That’s irrelevant

Comment: @AlBrown do you have these comments under the right place (in re opinion?)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes is wrong location. Thanks. I guess my other comment was clear (that it was about Job). Thanks God bless

Comment: @Northlight2018 my comment above. Hes just referring to Job’s evil relative being quoted I believe

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to how the author of Genesis would know about creation, and the author of both books may very well have been Moses. Therefore, as other people have said, God would've revealed the details of the events to the author. Alternatively, the entire story of Job may not have even happened. This doesn't mean that the story isn't truth, as it could be a parable that teaches true principles and concepts, and, if this is the case, the story would still come from God's inspiration, as 2 Timothy 3: 16 says, "“All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness."

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).
For some tips on writing good answers here, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394)
Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible speaks of this conversation between Satan and God, pertaining to Job and his faith. As far as I can tell, Satan does not dwell in hell, he's actually roaming the Earth until the Battle of Gog and Magog, after which he gets tossed into the lake of fire.

So did this conversation happen on Earth, or in heaven? Did God come to the Earth to speak to satan? Or was Satan allowed into heaven to talk to God?